# creating realtime graph from reading a json file from url

Tags: java, html, json

I have been working on an application that retrieves the time series data file from `Kairosdb` database which is installed on my local machine. The retrieved data looks something like this

> <200
>   OK,{"queries":[{"sample_size":90,"results":[{"name":"DummyPlantC_flood_10min_50","values":[[1216340434000,0],[1216426834000,0],[1216513234000,0],[1216599634000,15],[1216686034000,0],[1216772434000,0],[1216858834000,0],[1216945234000,0],[1217031634000,1],[1217118034000,1],[1217204434000,0],[1217290834000,0],[1217377234000,4],[1217463634000,8],[1217550034000,0],[1217636434000,0],[1217722834000,2],[1217809234000,2],[1217895634000,0],[1217982034000,0],[1218068434000,0],[1218154834000,0],[1218241234000,0],[1218327634000,0],[1218414034000,0],[1218500434000,0],[1218586834000,1],[1218673234000,0],[1218759634000,4],[1218846034000,0],[1218932434000,0],[1219018834000,0],[1219105234000,0],[1219191634000,4],[1219278034000,0],[1219364434000,0],[1219450834000,0],[1219537234000,0],[1219623634000,0],[1219710034000,1],[1219796434000,0],[1219882834000,0],[1219969234000,0],[1220055634000,0],[1220142034000,0],[1220228434000,0],[1220314834000,0],[1220401234000,1],[1220487634000,2],[1220574034000,0],[1220660434000,2],[1220746834000,0],[1220833234000,2],[1220919634000,0],[1221006034000,0],[1221092434000,2],[1221178834000,0],[1221265234000,0],[1221351634000,0],[1221438034000,0],[1221524434000,2],[1221610834000,2],[1221697234000,0],[1221783634000,0],[1221870034000,1],[1221956434000,0],[1222042834000,3],[1222129234000,2],[1222215634000,65],[1222302034000,91],[1222388434000,47],[1222474834000,0],[1222561234000,0],[1222647634000,0],[1222734034000,5],[1222820434000,2],[1222906834000,8],[1222993234000,49],[1223079634000,24],[1223166034000,1],[1223252434000,11],[1223338834000,0],[1223425234000,2],[1223511634000,2],[1223598034000,31],[1223684434000,72],[1223770834000,88],[1223857234000,82],[1223943634000,56],[1224030034000,45]]}]}]},{Access-Control-Allow-Origin=[*],
>   Pragma=[no-cache], Cache-Control=[no-cache], Expires=[0],
>   Content-Type=[application/json; charset=UTF-8],
>   Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Server=[Jetty(8.1.8.v20121106)]}>

the url where i reads this file is

```
http://localhost:8083/cloud%20dashboard//api/v1/ceilometer/cpuutil?ceilometerHost=a
```

I want to put the above `json` file into graph in my web application. How can I parse this `json` data into graph from the url?

I have tried parsing by some methods but unfortunately my `json` file contains some other stuffs like response code 200 ok and jetty server specifications and all that.

Comment: What kind of charts ? Bar chart, Line ? With which javascript library ?

Comment: If you're using jQuery for ajax request you can get returned by its success function like `success: function (data) {var results=data.queries[0].results}` and then you can use results for chart depending on your library you used